# Tcl - how to load Memchan linked statically?

Tags: tcl, static-libraries

I am trying to use [`Memchan`](http://memchan.sourceforge.net/) package in my application. I was able to compile and link it statically. But unfortunately I don't know how to load this package in my application.

```
% rs
Internal error detected during start: can't find package Memchan
can't find package Memchan
    while executing
"package require Memchan"
```

I traced this to the `pkgIndex.tcl` in `Memchan2.3` directory:

```
% cat pkgIndex.tcl
package ifneeded Memchan 2.3  [list load [file join $dir libMemchan2.3.so]]
```

I have two questions:

- How do I load the statically linked version `libMemchan2.3.a` ?
- Is there a special syntax for calling `package require Memchan` when one calls a statically linked library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a statically linked memchan package? Well, that means you need a different package index, whose contents should be this:

```
package ifneeded Memchan 2.3 {load {} Memchan}
```

The `load` has an empty first argument so that statically-linked libraries are considered, but without the filename, a second argument is needed in order to locate the initialization function (which will be `Memchan_Init` with the above value).

*Alternatively,* just do this at the start of your script:

```
load {} Memchan
```

That will cause the internal `package provide` to be done anyway, so that any future `package require Memchan`s will just succeed immediately on the grounds that the package is already in use.

---

[Background info]: As you can see, a package index file is actually very simple: it just provides some instructions to say that if you need a particular package of a particular version, here's a script to make it available. The only real nuance is that the `$dir` variable describes the location of the package index file while the file is being loaded.